# How to know the number of active validators in Solana

Tags: validator, data, node, decentralization

I would like to know how many Solana validator nodes are running actually.

Is there a way to get this data ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

First, you can use the solana command-line tool (https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools) like so:

solana validators

This will show a list of validators in the current validator set.

Also you can look at one of several websites, probably the canonical one being:

https://solanabeach.io/validators

However this website will show all validators that ever existed, including ones that have shut down long ago, so you will have to do your own analysis to exclude ones that you think are not viable any more in order to count only active validators.

Answer (score 0):

with javascript

```
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl } = require("@solana/web3.js");
const main = async () => {
  // establish the connection with solana
  // processed is level of commitment.
  // commitment level tells how certain we want to be of the blockchain data. `processed` means we retrieve the latest block that was confirmed by the node we are connected to
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), "processed");
  // current means active, delinquent means inactive validators
  const { current, delinquent } = await connection.getVoteAccounts();
  // this will be array of validators
  console.log("currents", current);
  console.log("size", current.length);
};
```